# Trying to update database only works for the first one

Tags: database, vb.net

i am making a program which can read and modify data on a database, currently it reads and displays data fine. the problem is when i come to update it it will only save the first value properly. all the data is inputted by text boxes on a form, there is several text boxes each going to a different value on the database. currently it updates the value from the first text box ("staffTitle") then changes all the new values to the previous values and saves the rest of the data.

```
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(DataAdapter)

    Dim oktick, rowNum As Integer

    rowNum = staffIDnumbers.Text

    rowNum = CInt(rowNum)

    rowNum = rowNum - 1
    dataset.Tables("staff").Rows(rowNum).Item(1) = staffTitle.Text
    dataset.Tables("staff").Rows(rowNum).Item(2) = Stafffirstname.Text
    dataset.Tables("staff").Rows(rowNum).Item(3) = Staffsurname.Text
    dataset.Tables("staff").Rows(rowNum).Item(4) = Staffpreferredname.Text
    dataset.Tables("staff").Rows(rowNum).Item(5) = Staffusepreferredname.Checked
    dataset.Tables("staff").Rows(rowNum).Item(6) = Staffstationrank.Text
    dataset.Tables("staff").Rows(rowNum).Item(7) = staffnotes.Text
    DataAdapter.Update(dataset, "staff")
    MsgBox("update complet", , "System Status")
```

this works if i use a number instead of "rowNum" but i cant work it without "rowNum"

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You probably should set Option Strict On ... you are doing some funny stuff with rowNum there... also you might want to check out Integer.Parse(...)